# Can you use this causative structure even if you are the one who actually makes the bed: "It is always nice when you have your bed made."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, causatives

This is from a native speaker who teaches English. here is the source: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecF1y2bI2T4) (minute:second 1:22-1:25)

**"The first thing I like to do after I get up is I like to make the bed. It is always nice when you have your bed made."**

The structure **"...have your bed made..."** seems to have a causative structure (have something done), but the meaning is not a causative. He is the one who makes the bed. He is not asking or hiring anyone to make his bed.

So, why is he using a causative structure whereas he is not asking someone to do it? or Does the structure (have+something+done) not always have a causative meaning, but rather have the meaning of the verb "keep", for instance **"It is always nice when you keep your bed made."****

Comment: Who is 'he'? Is he a native speaker?

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes he is a native speaker, Bob the Canadian, who teaches English online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, out of context I would understand 'have your bed made' as meaning 'have someone make your bed for you', so I find his usage somewhat unusual. (Also, don't most people leave the bed to air for a while after they get out of it?)

I don't know why he says it like that, but I suppose he means "It's always nice to have your bedroom in a tidy condition with the bed made."

Answer (score 1):

It is ambiguous, and could have either sense. But in the absence of any evidence to the contrary, people would take the *have ... made* as causitive.

(It has been argued that this kind ambiguity is precisely how the perfect arose in English and other languages: *I have [the letter written]* (I possess the letter, which has been written) reanalysed as *I have [the letter] written* -> *I have written the letter*.)